# Output of program that counts blanks, tabs, and newlines

Tags: c

### my question regards the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
// program counts blanks, tabs, and new lines
main()
{
    int c;
    int blank, tab, newl;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        } if (c == '    ') {
            ++blank;
        } if (c == '\t') {
            ++tab;
        } if (c == '\n') {
            ++newl;
    }

    printf("There are %d blank lines, %d tabs, and %d new lines\n", blank, tab, newl);
}
```

---

When I press CTRL+Z, my output is: There are 8 blank lines, 56 tabs, 2147344384 new lines

1) Why is this the programs output? 
2) Where is the getchar() getting this input from? 
3) Also when I execute the program in the MinGw console, why is it when I press ENTER the program continually moves to the next line? Only after I press CTRL+Z do I get the above mentioned output.

Thanks.

Comment: You never initialize your counters: `blank, tab, newl`. And read `getchar()`'s manual to understand how it works.

Comment: All of your variables start at a random value.

Comment: You tagged your question ANSI but your code is not following this standard.

Comment: Thanks guys. Sorry bout the ANSI, the C programming book I have says ANSI C on it. Don't know what it means, so I'll take the tag off.

Answer (score 4):

Smaller, simpler version:

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    int count[255] = {0};

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        count[c]++;
    }

    printf("There are %d blank lines, %d tabs, and %d new lines\n",
        count[' '],
        count['\t'],
        count['\n']);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just initialize the variables

```
#include<stdio.h>
// program counts blanks, tabs, and new lines
int
main()
{
    int c;
    int blank, tab, newl;

    blank = tab = newl = 0;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        // } if (c == '    ') { this is wong
        if (c == ' ') {
            ++blank;
        } else if (c == '\t') { // add else, you don't need to check this if the previous was true.
            ++tab;
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            ++newl;
        }
    }

    printf("There are %d blank lines, %d tabs, and %d new lines\n", blank, tab, newl);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, you could use a `swtich`.